# free up /boot .. can't install new software

Tags: boot, kernel, disk-usage

I was trying to install Mixxx to see how well it would work with Calf/other JACK programs, but when it started installing it gave me an error saying out there wasn't any free space on /boot

looking at other's questions on askubuntu and the ubuntu forums, I guess I'm kind of confused, because I didn't see any that dealt with just software, not upgrades or kernel installations.

I did

```
uname -r
3.8.0-31 generic
```

and then

```
sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'
```

which gave back a few results, numbering from 3.8.0-19 through 3.8.0-31.46

Maybe the other posts were just older in general, but other posts were saying to get rid of kernels like 2.6 and 2.8, but not anything this recent. Is it okay to delete all the kernels that aren't the 3.8.0-31 generic one?

Comment: Short answer, yes.

Answer (score 0):

When you dist-upgrade you move on to the new kernel. Excepting troubles you'd never normally boot into one of the older kernels you've left behind. Me I like to remove all but the most recent two of linux-image* and linux-headers* once I've accumulated four or five. I have jettisoned 3.8.0-19.30 through 3.8.0-26.38, and I'm due for another cleaning.

I don't know why an app would affect /boot though. Are you perhaps, I don't know, picking up a low latency kernel in the same installation?